# How to use string tokenizer when reading in from a file?

Tags: java, calculator

I am implementing a RPN calculator in Java and need help creating a class to parse the equations into separate tokens.

My input file will have an unknown number of equations similar to the ones shown below:

```
49+62*61-36
4/64
(53+26)
0*72
21-85+75-85
90*76-50+67
46*89-15
34/83-38
20/76/14+92-15
```

I have already implemented my own generic stack class to be used in the program, but I am now trying to figure out how to read data from the input file. Any help appreciated.

I've posted the source code for my stack class at [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/XESBr4vk), in case it may help.

I have also uploaded the Calculator with no filereading to [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/1LYQ6Q7a) to show what I have done already.

I have now managed to get the file read in and the tokens broken up thanks for the help. I am getting an error when it reaches the end of the file and was wondering how to solve that?

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

 public class TestClass {    
  static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 File file = new File("testEquations.txt");
  String[] lines = new String[10];
  try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
    int x = 0;
    String s;
    while((s = buffReader.readLine()) != null){
        lines[x] = s;
        x++;
    }
 }
  catch(IOException e){
    System.exit(0);
}
String OPERATORS = "+-*/()";

for (String st : lines) {
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(st, OPERATORS, true);
    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = tokens.nextToken();
        if (OPERATORS.contains(token))
            handleOperator(token);
        else
            handleNumber(token);
    }
     }
   }

private static void handleNumber(String token) {
System.out.println(""+token);

   }

 private static void handleOperator(String token) {
System.out.println(""+token);

  }
  }
```

Also How would I make sure the RPN works line by line? I am getting quite confused by the algorithms I am trying to follow.

Comment: How is the stack class related to reading/parsing the file?

Comment: You can read line by line, put the different lines in an ArrayList for example. After that tokenize the different expressions, parse them and calculate the result. You can see similar (may be a little bit more complex example) here http://github.com/mgechev/ELang

Comment: Thanks for the help.

The stack class is there as I need to use that to create the stack to store the tokens when calculating the answers instead of using the built in java utils.

Comment: Depending on whether your input includes negative numbers, you may have to pay some attention to expressions like `7*-2`

Comment: there will be no negative numbers in the files provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question has now changed completely from it's original version - this is in response to your original one, which was how to use FileReader to get the values from your file.

This will put each line into a separate element of a String array.  You should probably use an ArrayList instead, as it's far more flexible, but I have just done this as a quick demo - you can clean it up as you wish, although I notice the code you are using expects a String array as it's input.  Perhaps you could read the values initially into an ArrayList, then copy that to an array once you have all the lines - that way you can put as many lines in as you wish and keep your code flexible for changes in the number of lines in your input file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestClass {    
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("myfile.txt");
    String[] lines = new String[10];
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        int x = 0;
        String s;
        while((s = buffReader.readLine()) != null){
            lines[x] = s;
            x++;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        //handle exception
    }
    // And just to prove we have the lines right where we want them..
    for(String st: lines)
    System.out.println(st);
  }
}
```

You mentioned before that you were using the code on this link:

http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/a-mathematical-expression-parser-in-java/#more-1658

This appears to already deal with operator precedence doesn't it?  And with parsing each String from the array and sorting them into numbers or operators?  From my quick look it at least it appears to do that.

So it looks like all you need is for your lines to be in a String array, which you then pass to the code you already have.  From what I can see anyway.

Obviously this doesn't address the issue of numbers greater than 9, but hopefully it helps with the first half.

:-)

Comment: Hi thanks for that. combining your code with the answer below I have managed to get all my tokens out of the class but get an error when it reaches the end of the file. how do i stop this happening?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException and it is regards to the line
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(st, OPERATORS, true);

Comment: after reading the last line of the file, it seems to be reading in a null value, which is where your error is occurring.  If you wrap your while loop (including this line:   StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(st, OPERATORS, true);  ) in an if statement checking whether st is null, then it works without error.    e.g.  if(st != null){...}

Comment: I was thinking of creating my own method and was wondering how i would determine precedence? would I be able to just modify the code I already have to work with the new tokenizer I have?

here is the link to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436147/how-to-implement-shunting-yard-and-rpn

Answer (score 4):

Because all of the operators are single characters, you can instruct `StringTokenizer` to return them along with the numeric tokens.

```
String OPERATORS = "+-*/()";
String[] lines = ...

for (String line : lines) {
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(line, OPERATORS, true);
    while (tokens.hasMoreTOkens()) {
        String token = tokens.nextToken();
        if (OPERATORS.contains(token))
            handleOperator(token);
        else
            handleNumber(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: My answer addresses your original question about using a string tokenizer to parse the equations. Note that those equations use infix operations--*not* RPN. I would separate your problem into multiple single-issue questions if you hope to receive meaningful help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the helo David. I have now managed to read the file in and get the tokens. now how would i set precedence? thanks

Comment: @Ph9 - Welcome to StackOverflow. :) Please start a new question about operator precedence or how RPN works. SO is different from forum sites in that each question should ultimately address a single, narrow, answerable topic. I recommend a quick read of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    double sum=0;
    int count = 0 ;
    try {
        String nomFichier = "Fichier.txt";
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(nomFichier);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String ligneLue;

        do {
            ligneLue = br.readLine();
            if(ligneLue != null) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(ligneLue, ";");
                String nom = st.nextToken();
                String prenom = st.nextToken();
                String age = st.nextToken();
                String tele = st.nextToken();
                String adress = st.nextToken();
                String codePostal = st.nextToken();
                String ville = st.nextToken();
                String paye = st.nextToken();
                double note = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
                count++;
            }
        }
        while(ligneLue != null);
        br.close();
        double mediane = count / 2; 
        if(mediane % 2 == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Le mediane dans le fichier est " + mediane);
        }
        else {
            mediane +=1;   
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Le mediane dans le fichier est " + mediane);
        }
    }//fin try
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }               
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?