# Java stringtokenizer assignment trouble

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

So I'm having trouble with an assignment where I need to return the first or second token of a string, based on the given argument, using the stringtokenizer constructs and methods. EX: "3+5", 2. the return on this should be 5.
Now what I have so far is:

```
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (input, "+-*/%");
      if (st.hasMoreTokens());
    return st.nextToken();
```

this returns the first token of the string, but im unsure of how to return the second token. any advice?

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (st.hasMoreTokens());
```

Should be

```
  if (st.hasMoreTokens())
```

There is an extra `;`, With that extra `;`  your code like writing,

```
if(..)
{

}

 return st.nextToken();
```

Edit :

Moreover you need to form a string and then return. Not  `return st.nextToken();`  that terminates your loop and returns the first value.

Comment: Thank you, that did help me a bit. But im still uncertain about returning the second token based on the given argument

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. For this program to work, we need two parameters - *Input String*, *position of the wanted token*. In the below program, I have hard coded the position of the
wanted token as '**3**'. so, the output would be '**10**', since it is the third token of the input string - `3+5*10*12+11`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //input string 
    String input = "3+5*10*12+11";
    // number of token we need
    int wantedToken = 3;
    // token number defaults to '1' and keeps track of the token position
    int i = 1;
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, "+-*/%");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        //when i equals wanted token, print it
        if (i == wantedToken) {
            System.out.println("wanted token : " + st.nextToken());
            break;
        } 
        else {
            //move to next token
            st.nextToken();
            //increment the token position
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
run:
wanted token : 10
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Update: Converted the above code - a Seperate Method. The below code takes `input string and wanted token from user`

```
public class WantedTokenTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          //input string 
        String input = null;
        // number of token we need
        int wantedToken = 1;
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the input string : ");
       input =  scr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the wanted token : ");
       wantedToken =  scr.nextInt();

        System.out.println(getWantedToken(input, wantedToken));

    }


    private static String getWantedToken(String input,int wantedToken){
           // token number defaults from '1' and keeps track of the token position
        int i = 1;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, "+-*/%");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            //when i equals wanted token, print it
            if (i == wantedToken) {
               return st.nextToken();

            } 
            else {
                //move to next token
                st.nextToken();
                //increment the token position
                i++;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope, it clarifies how to do it

Comment: This was vey helpful, thank you! I have one more question though, I did not make this very clear but how would you return any token within the equation without hardcoding it in? As if the user input the token they want.

Comment: Just get the wanted token from user using *Scanner* API and make this code as a seperate method with two parameters. i.e. input string, position of the wanted token

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
 /... 
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse math expression with Tokenizer you should do it dinamically.
You could take a look at [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498649/advanced-tokenizer-for-a-complex-math-expression?answertab=votes#tab-top) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432094/how-to-use-string-tokenizer-when-reading-in-from-a-file).

But if you just want to get the second token try this code:

```
public static List<String> getTokens(String input) {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input, "+-*/%");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tokens.add(st.nextToken());
    }
    return tokens;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List tokens = getTokens("3+5");
    System.out.println(tokens.get(0));
    System.out.println(tokens.get(1));//the second token
}
```

OR

```
public static String[] getTokens (String input) {
    return input.split("[-\\+\\*\\\\]");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tokens = getTokens("3+5");
    System.out.println(tokens[0]);
    System.out.println(tokens[1]);//the second token
}
```